# How to properly link the style of an element?

Tags: html, css

So I am working on a project and I found some code online. This code really helped my project responsive menubalk with html and css only.

Now I have all the style correct and I am trying to implement it in my site by instead targeting generic blocks like  or  using classes and id's. This give me some problems because for some reason it doesn't work and I am not really sure what the problem is.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Gautami', Arial;
}
#menu {
  width: 100%;
}
#MenuActive {
  background-color: #e5e6e8;
}
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/

ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/

li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
/*Style for menu links*/

li a {
  display: block;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #2072ba;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*Hover state for top level links*/

li:hover a {
  background: #e5e6e8;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
/*Style for dropdown links*/

li:hover ul a {
  background: #2072ba;
  color: white;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li:hover ul a:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #2072ba;
}
/*Hover state for dropdown links*/

li:hover ul a:hover {
  background: #e5e6e8;
  color: #2072ba;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/

li ul {
  display: none;
}
/*Make dropdown links vertical*/

li ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}
/*Prevent text wrapping*/

li ul li a {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
/*Display the dropdown on hover*/

ul li a:hover + .hidden,
.hidden:hover {
  display: block;
}
#right {
  float: right;
}
/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/

.show-menu {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2072ba;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14.5px 0px 14.5px 0px;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}
/*Hide checkbox*/

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu {
  display: block;
}
#content {
  border: solid 5px grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.text {
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
  border: solid 5px #2072ba;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.titel {
  text-align: center;
  color: #2072ba;
}
.line {
  margin: 20px;
  height: 1px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(white), to(white), color-stop(25%, #2072ba));
}
/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (min-width: 1201px) /*lower this number to show the big menubalk or resize your screen but always keep this value 1px above the other one or they will interfere*/ {
  body {
    padding-top: 61px;
  }
  #MenuDiv {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #menu {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2072ba;
    top: 0;
  }
  #MenuActive {
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  li:hover a {
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  #content {
    margin: 20px 10% 20px 10%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) /*lower this number to show the big menubalk or resize your screen*/ {
  .show-menu {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #2072ba;
  }
  /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
  ul {
    position: static;
    display: none;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  /*Create vertical spacing*/
  li {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #2072ba;
  }
  /*Make all menu links full width*/
  ul li,
  li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /*Display 'show menu' link*/
  .show-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  #right {
    float: none;
  }
  #content {
    margin: 20px 5% 20px 5%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="again.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li id="MenuActive"><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Diensten</a>
      </li>
      <li><a chref="#">Keurmerken</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <div id="right">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Mijn account &darr;</a>
          <ul class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#">Diensten</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Account informatie</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Inloggen</a>
        </li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="text">
      <h1 class="titel">Hallo</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sed purus eget ipsum eleifend vehicula. In suscipit dapibus mi in semper. Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi scelerisque tempus ullamcorper. Donec malesuada, velit id consequat venenatis, lorem
        risus dignissim eros, id porta tortor lorem et tortor. Vivamus quis odio sit amet est varius auctor. Aliquam scelerisque erat ligula, vel finibus arcu euismod id. Ut arcu nisl, condimentum sed pulvinar ut, tincidunt quis nisl. In hac habitasse
        platea dictumst. Cras nec sagittis erat, eu posuere risus. Donec vitae lacinia sem, nec lacinia orci. Nullam varius dignissim ligula vitae bibendum. Sed egestas ante id lobortis interdum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see the code works perfectly but as soon as you try to add classes, the dropdown menu gets affected or the entire menu. Because I am relative new to css I don't know why it shouldn't work because when adding classes to dropdownlinks and only add style to those links it is not working.

So I would like to know how to link the style properly so it doesn't go wrong in the future.

E: I mean instead of using "li ul li a" or "li a" I want to use a class or id but that doesn't work.

Thanks!

PS) if you enlarge the result it will show you a different menubalk.

Comment: I am sorry, the example is looking fine. So when does it break? What exactly did you add, and where?

Comment: I don't get it. Where exactly did you add classes and what happens? EDIT: O.K., after thinking about it, I quess you're adding a class to a dropdown `<li>` element but don't want the children (`<ul>`s) to be affected. Is it correct?

Comment: As you can see the style file is using "li ul" and I want to add this menu to my site but I need to change "li ul" to a class because otherwise other lists in my site will change to look like the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use CSS classes or ids to separate out the new styles from your websites existing styles. That should avoid the issue you're having where it's changing everything on your website.

For example (using an id):

Since you have this already in your html:

```
<ul id="menu">
      <li id="MenuActive">
      </li>
</ul>
```

You can update your CSS to use the `menu` id:

```
ul#menu {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

ul#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
/* And so on and so forth... */
```

---

Or for a class, simply update your html to:

```
<ul id="menu" class="nav-menu">
      <li id="MenuActive">
      </li>
</ul>
```

And your CSS to:

```
ul.nav-menu {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

ul.nav-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
/* Etc... */
```

Comment: It's not necessary to specify element type on id selectors. In this case it's also unnecessary to specify it on the class selectors.